# TeamCity - getting ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN - how to find Secure properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, msbuild, teamcity

I just inherited TeamCity, I haven't used it before. I'm having issues trying to get a web deploy for a new build I just created (copied from another build that does work).

When the build tries to deploy to Server 2012 I get:  **ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN**

I understand ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN is also thrown when the password is incorrect.

The issue I have is there are 2 Usernames and 2 passwords listed in the configuration.

I have checked all servers using : http://[servername].amazonaws.com/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE

using one UN/PW (that I know) and they work.

The other password I cannot figure out what is saved in Team City. I cannot figure out how to access the property:
    %secure:teamcity.password.system.Password%

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly I even asked. After shaking my head, I realized the old dev's used the servers build in Administrator account for all deploys (red flag). I decided to scrap that and build in all new accounts for TC Deploys to limit the scope of that account.

now it's working like a charm.